# How to use DI in DbSet

Tags: entity-framework

I want to implement business logic in DbSet derived classes. I like the idea of not having services and DAL abstractions and think this could be a good way. For this to work I need to inject objects into my DbSet but I don't know how. Here some sample code which does not work, because the EF Framework can't create an object of the DbSet. Maybe someone can point me in the right direction?

```
public class LongTermBookingDbSet : DbSet<LongTermBooking>
{
    DbContext _dbContext { get; set; }

    public LongTermBookingDbSet(DbContext dbContext )
    {
        this._dbContext = _bContext ;
    }

    public override LongTermBooking Add(LongTermBooking entity)
    {
        return this.Add(entity, false);   
    }

    public LongTermBooking Add(LongTermBooking entity, bool SendMails)
    {
        var dbSet = base.Add(entity);

        //do something with the _dbContext

        return dbSet;
    }
}
```

Comment: This makes me a bit uncomfortable if I'm honest. You are now mixing your domain code with your business logic and sending mails. I'd keep them separated.

Comment: I see. I changed the example to some other reference to not confuse that, because I more or less want to know how to inject anything there

Comment: The right direction is: back. Don't use DbSet for anythings else than what it's intended for. Whatever you're trying to achieve, there are better ways.

Answer (score 0):

One of the options is to aggregate real `DbSet`, not derive it:

```
public class PersonSet : IDbSet<Person>
{
    private readonly DbSet<Person> _dbSet;

    public PersonSet(DbSet<Person> dbSet)
    {
        _dbSet = dbSet;
    }
}

public class MyDbContext: DbContext
{
    public PersonSet PersonSet {...}
}
```

[Inherits from DbSet<T> with the purposes to add property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20427936/inherits-from-dbsett-with-the-purposes-to-add-property)