# Inheriting dbset to add new methods

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, inheritance, dbset

I'm trying to inherit a dbset from my dbcontext to codify new methods in it. I wouldn't like to create an extension, I prefer an inherited class to preserve original dbset to other tasks.
I've seen this link:

[Inherits from DbSet<T> with the purposes to add property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20427936/inherits-from-dbsett-with-the-purposes-to-add-property)

but I need it in VB, this is in C# and I don't know how to translate it.
Is this a good way? Any new suggestion? Can you help me translate previous post?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: [c# to vb.net convertion tool](http://converter.telerik.com/)

Comment: Thanks Eminem, I tried it but things like IDerivedDbSet interface declaration are not, escape me and I don't know how to code.

Comment: I dont see any code in that answer that you can not convert using the conversion tool. The c# code in the answer is very similer to its fellow VB.Net code. Just remove some brackets etc...

Comment: My problem is with IDerivedDbSet interface. I do not know how to declare. The rest of the code is perfectly translated.

Comment: [Interfaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28e2e18x.aspx)

Comment: Thanks again. My problem is with this in particular.